# How to plot several curve segments on the same graph?

Tags: r, plot

```
seg1 <- function(t) 0.01000000+0.01021486*t+0.00915602*t^2-0.01485179*t^3
curve(seg1, 0, 2/12)

seg2 <- function(t) 0.01145666+0.00758914*t+0.01521279*t^2+0.09378380*t^3
curve(seg2, 2/12, 5/12)

seg3 <- function(t) 0.00000000+0.02320514*t+0.00490835*t^2-0.08080547*t^3
curve(seg3, 5/12, 11/12)

seg4 <- function(t) 0.02215231-0.02425796*t-0.00962054*t^2+0.02154812*t^3
curve(seg4, 11/12, 15/12)
```

join the 4 segments in the same graph using same scale, with interval from 0 to 1.25

---

My orginal input is incorrect.
Using the correct input i got a smooth curve

> seg1 <- function(t) 0.0100000000000000 + 0.01145665803921569 *t + 0.02215231058823505 *t^3
>   curve(seg1, 0, 2/12, xlim=c(0,1.25), ylim=c(-.1,.1))
>
> seg2 <- function(t) 0.0102148623819898 + 0.00758913516339875 *t + 0.02320513725490168 *t^2 - 0.02425796392156832 *t^3 
>   curve(seg2, 2/12, 5/12, add=TRUE)
>
> seg3 <- function(t) 0.0091560208106391 + 0.01521279447712401 *t + 0.00490835490196105 *t^2 - 0.00962053803921581 *t^3
>   curve(seg3, 5/12, 11/12, add=TRUE)
>
> seg4 <- function(t) -0.0148517859681374 + 0.09378379848039248 *t - 0.08080546764705908 *t^2 + 0.02154812470588242 *t^3
>   curve(seg4, 11/12, 15/12, add=TRUE)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `add=TRUE` argument. And you need to specify `xlim` and `ylim` values in the initial `curve`.

```
seg1 <- function(t) 0.01000000+0.01021486*t+0.00915602*t^2-0.01485179*t^3
curve(seg1, 0, 2/12, xlim=c(0,1.25), ylim=c(-.1,.1))

seg2 <- function(t) 0.01145666+0.00758914*t+0.01521279*t^2+0.09378380*t^3
curve(seg2, 2/12, 5/12, add=TRUE)

seg3 <- function(t) 0.00000000+0.02320514*t+0.00490835*t^2-0.08080547*t^3
curve(seg3, 5/12, 11/12, add=TRUE)

seg4 <- function(t) 0.02215231-0.02425796*t-0.00962054*t^2+0.02154812*t^3
curve(seg4, 11/12, 15/12, add=TRUE)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for me to plot the corresponding seg(x) points and values of x=(0, 2/12, 5/12, 11/12, 15/12)  ?

Comment: Sounds like you either want to add `points` to the plot, or pass a `type='p'` (points) or `type='b'` (points and lines) argument in all of the `curve` functions, but I'm not totally clear.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out how to plot them nicely now.
points(xy.coords(2/12, seg1(2/12)), add=TRUE)
points(xy.coords(5/12, seg2(5/12)), add=TRUE)
points(xy.coords(11/12, seg3(11/12)), add=TRUE)
points(xy.coords(15/12, seg4(15/12)), add=TRUE)

text(2/12, seg1(2/12), seg1(2/12), cex=0.5, pos=1, col="black")
text(5/12, seg2(5/12), seg2(5/12), cex=0.5, pos=1, col="black")
text(11/12, seg3(11/12), seg3(11/12), cex=0.5, pos=1, col="black")
text(15/12, seg4(15/12), seg4(15/12), cex=0.5, pos=1, col="black")